# Sharing img's from Scene7 to social media

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, pinterest, scene7

I'm having problems sharing the rendered images onto social media, namely Facebook & Pinterest (didn't try it on anything else yet). The images are scenes from different rooms in a house where you can adjust things like the colour of the furniture, kind of floor, etc. 
It DOES work when I give the link where nothing has changed yet, the basic image of the scene without coloured objects, no floor, etc. But from the moment I change anything it doesn't work any more. Even if I put it's quality and resolution at it's lowest it doesn't work.

The facebook crawler says:

> Provided og:image,  could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb or your server was too slow to respond.

Now, when it did work with the basic image it said the same thing, and it worked.
I can't get it to work with either the og:image meta tag as well as doing it through the API in javascript

Pinterest says:

> Sorry we could not fetch the image

Even though on the share screen I see a preview of the image, when I post it this error is given.
The console also states (with the working as well as with the non working image) that the mixed content was blocked (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content)

This is how a link to these images looks like *(it won't work because it's an example on how it looks like out of privacy of the client)*
Any ideas on how to make this work?

This works

> http://company.scene7.com/is/image/CompanyRender/?src=ir{CompanyRender/room01-day}&hei=400&fmt=jpg&qlt=90&op_sharpen=1

This does not work

> http://company.scene7.com/is/image/CompanyRender/?src=ir{CompanyRender/room01-day?obj=floor&src=is{CompanyRender/flr_400379-n-h?layer=1&blendMode=mult&color=255,255,255}&rotate=180&gloss=0&res=110}&hei=400&fmt=jpg&qlt=90&op_sharpen=1

Ps. There is no 'Scene7' tag, shouldn't there be one?

Comment: "Bumping the question"

Comment: Last bumb before giving up

Comment: Just kidding i'm bumping it one more time